# The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control error?

Tags: html

This is driving me crazy. I know its something to do with the label tag. here is my code:

```
 <form method="post" action="includes/loginprocess.php">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value=''/>

    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

The for and name are both the same?

The error is "The for attribute of the label element must refer to a form control."

Comment: I think the label's `for` references the element's `id`. So `label for='username'` and `input id='username'`.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_label_for.asp, the value of `for` attribute of a label should be the `id` of the element the label is bound to, so add `id` attribute to the textboxes

```
<form method="post" action="includes/loginprocess.php">
    <label for="username">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=''/>

    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: you were faster by 21 sec :)

Comment: w3chools is neither authoritative nor correct, so it should not be cited. See http://w3fools.com